# How to use multiple ? in prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I want to run a select statement with PHP using multiple '?'. How do I do that?
I think the following code should do that, what is wrong?

```
$con = mysql_connect("database","login","password");
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("posdictionary", $con);

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM WordPOS WHERE WORD LIKE '?%' AND pos LIKE BINARY '%?%'");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $pattern, $pos);
$pattern = $_POST["pattern"];
$pos = $_POST["pos"];

$value = "";
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $value = $value . $row['word'] . " " . $row['pos'] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

The answers below are great. I had an error in my PHP the '?%' is not legal in php sql statement. The query should look like this:

```
  $pattern = $_POST["pattern"] ."%";
  $pos = "%". $_POST["pos"] ."%";
  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT word, pos FROM WordPOS WHERE word LIKE ? AND pos LIKE BINARY ?");
```

Then follow the rest of the answers.

Comment: I cannot use mysqli because Dreamhost uses mysql, and does not support the mysqli commands.

Comment: Contact Dreamhost and discuss the issue with them.

Comment: @Whitecat [This seems to suggest](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Talk:Installing_PHP5) that Dreamhost's PHP5 does support MySQLi.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the prepared statement working wonderfully now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect with [`new MySQLi()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) instead of `mysql_connect()`, which is not compatible with MySQLi API.

```
$con = new MySQLi("database","login","password","posdictionary");
```

Your `prepare()` and `execute()` calls are correct, with your two parameters correctly bound.  However, your [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) isn't going to work because MySQLi expects result columns to be bound in variables via `bind_result()`, *not* into an array like `$row = $stmt->fetch())` as would be done with the old `mysql_*()` API or PDO.

```
  $pattern = $_POST["pattern"];
  $pos = $_POST["pos"];

  // Substituting explicit columns in the SELECT list
  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT word, pos FROM WordPOS WHERE WORD LIKE '?%' AND pos LIKE BINARY '%?%'");
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $pattern, $pos);

  // Bind result columns into vars $word, $pos
  $stmt->bind_result($word, $pos);

  // Then execute and fetch 
  $value = "";
  if ($stmt->execute()) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // Using the bound variables...
    $value .=  $word . " " . $pos . "<br />";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am using mysql_connect. Should i change to use mysqli? are the interchangeable?

Comment: @Whitecat Oh I didn't even notice that.... Yes, you need to be calling `new MySQLi()`

Comment: I copied your code into mine and it does not work still. The non prepared statement works though. I cannot add it below but I just have a mysql_query statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and then switching to mysqli syntax. That is not going to work, you need to change:

```
$con = mysql_connect("database","login","password");
 if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("posdictionary", $con);
```

to:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("database","login","password");
 if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

  mysqli_select_db("posdictionary", $con);
```

Comment: @Whitecat no, you don't have an mysqli connection open so you cannot do anything in mysqli.

Comment: I cannot use mysqli because Dreamhost uses mysql, and does not support the mysqli commands.

Comment: @Whitecat Then you would need to switch to all `mysql_` functions, switch to PDO or look for a different host. I would switch if I could not use PDO either as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and do not support prepared statements (insecure). By the way, I cannot imagine that a host does not support mysqli nor PDO.

Comment: What is PDO and how do I find if it is supported? Where are examples of PDO?

Comment: @Whitecat Look for the PDO section when you run `phpinfo();`. You need to have driver support for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I will first assign, then bind

```
$pattern = $_POST["pattern"];
$pos = $_POST["pos"];
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $pattern, $pos);
```